# How to to compute a FFT spectrum of observation data and extract the harmonics retaining the diurnal cycle?

Tags: python-2.7

Dear all python users,

I'm new in python and I want to use it to compute a FFT spectrum of observation data and extract the harmonics retaining the diurnal cycle. My data is composed by (time:262992 hours; site:46 stations), which is hourly air_temperature of 46 stations from 1983-2012. I have been able to plot time series of selected station (see the code below). Now I want to compute FFT spectrum of selected station (data[0] for instance), and extract the harmonic retaining the diurnal cycle. How to do it?
Python code:

```
import iris
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#Load the data
t_air = iris.load_cube('/home/amadou/anaconda/RainCell_python_mw_link_training/all_new.nc', 'air_temperature')
#Have a quick look
print t_air

#create a pandas data frame with each column representing a site
data=as_data_frame(t_air[:,0])
for i in range(0,t_air.coord('latitude').shape[0]):
    data[str(i)]=as_data_frame(t_air[:,i])

data.head()

#create a metadata list with lat/lon (each index represents the corresponding data frame column)
metadata=[]
for i in range(0,t_air.coord('latitude').shape[0]):
    lat = t_air[:,i].coord('latitude').points[0]
    lon = t_air[:,i].coord('longitude').points[0]
    metadata.append([lat,lon])

# now you do the pandas stuff (plotting,resampling,…) 
# Example for the monthly averages of the first site 
ax = data[0].resample('D')['2012-04':'2012-05'].plot(figsize=(10,5))
ax.legend([metadata[0]])
```

Is there anybody who can help me, from here, to compute a FFT spectrum of this data and extract the harmonics retaining the diurnal cycle?

Best